# How does the SQL IN keyword work when you use a select within a select?

Tags: sql, select

In SQL, you can use an IN like so:

```
SELECT name, continent
FROM world
WHERE continent IN (
    SELECT continent
    FROM world
    WHERE name IN ('Belize', 'Thailand') );
```

[source](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial)

But what I was accustomed to seeing was the IN being used like this:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN ('Happy','Happened','Fish');
```

So does SQL automatically turn the nested-select into something like this?

```
('Test1','Test2','Test3')
```

Comment: Nope, the inner query in your first example is executed first and then the `IN` is evaluated.

Comment: As a rule, using in against a sub query should be avoided in favor of a join.

Comment: @user2989408 - Ok, I see now .  So first inner query brings back Asia and N. America,  then that gets used with the IN

Comment: I guess you got confused. To evaluate the outter most query needs the values returned from the subquery and the subquery needs to match itself rows with the values passed in the in operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is NO. In fact the two examples you have provided are not even similar.
The inner query in your first example is executed first, and then the `IN` is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

The first example is a subquery (nested query), it will evaluated like this:

[image]

It will return a table, then filter main query that matches `Continent` in the **projected table**.

The second will filter main table that matches `Continent` in the **array** of values.

However, the result can be the same if first example return this:

```
column_name
---------
'Happy'
'Happened'
'Fish'
```

and the second query filter array is `('Happy','Happened','Fish')`.

I suspect that second query is faster.